# Why can we not have our `title` preview back with a popup like the `tags`?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

More and more I find myself missing the `title` preview that would pop up in the questions list on Stack Overflow. Why can't we get a question title preview back on mouseover similar to what is done for the `tags` on mouseover? Is it a bandwidth issue? That doesn't seem right, some of the popup tag descriptions are far longer than the old title previews used to be.

Any insight or discussion would be appreciated. I miss the title preview.

Answer (score 2):

From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292287/21960):

> We took the titles off as part of mitigating a DDoS attack on our servers - removing the title attribute has reduced the page size dramatically, meaning we could cope with the attack better.
>
> There are no plans for re-enabling it in the short term.

Comment: And this is why we can't have nice things.  Understandable to tilt towards the side of keeping the site actually available, though.

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense. The obsessive compulsive need to know side is now satisfied `:)`. Always impressed with Stack Exchange stewardship. I knew it wasn't done to just decrease functionality. Thanks.